# Django dependente drop down usando inline formset

Tags: javascript, django-2.0

estou seguindo este tutorial.

[How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Porém, estou tentando usar junto a ele o `inline formset`. Alguém já utilizou desta forma? Pois o meu problema esta no seguinte:

```
<script>
    $("#id_country").change(function () {
      var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-cities-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
      var countryId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

      $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
        data: {
          'country': countryId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
          $("#id_city").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

No final do código  `$("#id_city").html(data);` ele substitui os valores do campo `id_city` pelo valor que veio do server ok...

O problema está quando utilizo o `inline formset`, ele coloca os `id's` da seguinte maneira:

`id_city-0-exemplo`... e quando adiciona um novo `form` ele recebe 
`id_city-1-exemplo`... e assim por diante.

O problema é que no *javascript* tenho que passar exatamente o `id` do campo que irá receber o valor retornado do servidor.

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.